# Publishing not reflecting

Tags: asp.net, visual-sourcesafe

Using visual studio,changes are not reflecting on publishing even though on development side,it is showing.What can be the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using local iis server?

Comment: No Sandeep,am not using local server

Comment: are you using any web hosting site?

Comment: yes im hosting on another server

Comment: have you uploaded your published data correctly on server?

Comment: yes i have published it correctly

Comment: create new folder and publish your site to this new folder and add it to local iis and test whether it is working perfectly than upload same data to server. may be you are missing something or site is not getting published correctly.